# Assigning raster values to a label in R

Tags: raster, r

I have a raster, the pixel values inside the raster is equal to 1; outside is 0.
I would like to write an r function that assign these 1 values = "cloud" in other way it will return cloud. otherwise clear.

I would like to keep the result as DF. like in the photo; (the photo is the result of different code so I cannot apply that to this situation)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it in case someone needed;

```
recode_poly <- function(x){
  poly_recode = c()
  for (i in (1:1000)){
    if (x[i] == 1) {
      poly_label = "cloud" 
    } else {
      poly_label = "clear"
    }
    poly_recode <- c(poly_recode, poly_label)
  }
  return (poly_recode)
}
```

then you can convert **poly_recode** to a dataframe

but I am pretty open new solutions